# Updating rows dynamically in multi table UPDATE statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am exploring the multi-table update statement in MySQL. While playing with various combinations, I struck on some outputs that I couldn't understand. I tried on the internet but couldn't find anything.

Suppose I have two tables, `t1` and `t2`. I will update `t1` based on `t2` and will also update `t2`. I want to see if `t1` will keep up with the updated value of `t2` or not.

Here's the code.

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1(
  id INT
);

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1), (2), (1), (2);

CREATE TABLE t2(
  id INT,
  new_id INT
);

INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1, 8);
```

Now, if I run the following:

```sql
UPDATE t1, t2
SET t1.id = t2.new_id,
t2.new_id = t2.new_id + 2
-- ,t2.id = t2.id + 1
WHERE t1.id = t2.id 
-- or t1.id = t2.id + 1
;
```

The output is:

```
t2
+------+--------+
| id   | new_id |
+------+--------+
|    1 |     10 |
+------+--------+

t1
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    8 |
|    2 |
|   10 |
|    2 |
+------+
```

Here, `t1` kept up with the updated value of t2. I tried more combinations, as follows:

```sql
UPDATE t1, t2
SET t1.id = t2.new_id,
t2.new_id = t2.new_id + 2
,t2.id = t2.id + 1
WHERE t1.id = t2.id 
-- or t1.id = t2.id + 1
;

Output
t2
+------+--------+
| id   | new_id |
+------+--------+
|    2 |     10 |
+------+--------+

t1
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    8 |
|    2 |
|    8 |
|    2 |
+------+
```

Here, I expected that after the first row of t1 changed and t2 changed it's value to (2,10), t1 would see changes in the 2nd and 4th row (the ones corresponding to id = 2). However, the row with id = 1 changed, and that to not to the updated value.

I guessed that the WHERE clause ran before the query, and therefore, the rows with id = 2 didn't change. However, I couldn't guess what the reason was behind the change in the 3rd row and it taking the old value.

Then to confirm my guess regarding the WHERE clause running before, I ran the following query:

```sql
UPDATE t1, t2
SET t1.id = t2.new_id,
t2.new_id = t2.new_id + 2
-- ,t2.id = t2.id + 1
WHERE t1.id = t2.id 
or t1.id = t2.id + 1
;

Output
t2
+------+--------+
| id   | new_id |
+------+--------+
|    1 |     10 |
+------+--------+

t1
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    8 |
|   10 |
|   10 |
|   10 |
+------+
```

Surely, this time the 2nd and 4th row changed.

However, for curiosity I ran the remaining combination.

```sql
UPDATE t1, t2
SET t1.id = t2.new_id,
t2.new_id = t2.new_id + 2
,t2.id = t2.id + 1
WHERE t1.id = t2.id 
or t1.id = t2.id + 1
;

Output
t2
+------+--------+
| id   | new_id |
+------+--------+
|    2 |     10 |
+------+--------+

t1
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    8 |
|    8 |
|    8 |
|    8 |
+------+
```

Now, all the values are 8, whereas I expected only the 2nd and 4th row to change to 10 based on the updated t2.

Can anyone explain what I'm missing here? Also, is my assumption that WHERE is happening before correct? Any help is appreciated. If possible could anyone explain how UPDATE command works internally?

Comment: When you define `WHERE t1.id=t2.id` condition, that will take current column value that you use for the update as the update value. Therefore, when you get `t2.new_id` it's always `8` in that update. You'll need to use more operation/function to achieve what you want especially when you're aiming for dynamic update.

Comment: If you see in the first case, the value is 10.

Comment: Yes, maybe I'm wrong about "t2.new_id it's always 8".. but are you thinking that after `t1.id` is updated to `8`, each the next `t1.id` that matches with `t2.id` will add `+2`? For example if your `t1.id` values are `(1), (2), (1), (2), (1), (2), (1), (2)`, it will be updated to `(8), (2), (10), (2), (12), (2), (14), (2)`?

Comment: Which case are you talking about?

Comment: For 2nd, I think the output should be `(8), (2), (1), (2)`. For fourth, I think output should be `(8), (10), (1), (10)`.

Comment: I also keep in mind that one row can be changed only once as specified in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html#:~:text=Each%20matching%20row%20is%20updated%20once%2C%20even%20if%20it%20matches%20the%20conditions%20multiple%20times).